# Why "making it his object to let go" translated as "making to letting go to be his object"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "And what is the faculty of concentration? There is the case where a monk, a disciple of the noble ones, **making it his object to let go**, attains concentration, attains singleness of mind.

Why should "making it his object to let go" be translated as "making *to-let-go* be his object"?

Why does "it" refer to "to let go"?

Where can I learn the rule about this case?

Full content: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn48/sn48.010.than.html

Comment: The definition of [object](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/object) that applies here is "the goal or end of an effort or activity", so the sentence could be reworded "A monk, making it his goal to *let go*, attains concentration..."

Answer (score 1):

*It* in this case is being used as an indefinite pronoun, similar to *it's raining* or *it's cold outside.*

You can qualify the indefinite pronoun in a manner like *It's raining outside in Los Angeles.*

This can be done with *make* to mean *make the situation X* or *make what {someone} is doing now X*.